# Unable to convert project as VSProject

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, solution, envdte, vspackage

We have created solution like the one below and added the default project after creating solution. Please refer code below

```
        Type visualStudioType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0", true);
        DTE env = Activator.CreateInstance(visualStudioType, true) as DTE;
        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider(env as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider);
        DTE dte = (DTE)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
        Object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(visualStudioType, true);

        EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte8Obj = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)obj;

        Solution2 soln = (Solution2)dte8Obj.Solution;
```

1.I get exception like below, When create project solution.

[image: Solution explorer Exception]

2.After create project, We cannot able to convert project as VSProject. Its showing exception like below.

[image: Exception when convert project as vsproject]

Please give solution for resolve above mention issues .

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified to:

```
Type visualStudioType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0", true);

EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = Activator.CreateInstance(visualStudioType, true) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;

EnvDTE80.Solution2 soln = dte2.Solution as EnvDTE80.Solution2;
```

Regarding the error locating EnvDTE version 7.0.3300.0 see:

[Error When EnvDTE Is Used with VSLangProj Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228768.aspx)

Comment: Hi Carrlos,
Thanks for your response. I have tried to add app.config file like above your suggested, But issue not resolved.

Comment: Hi Carrlos,
I have tried to create project using above your suggest code snippet . But I get below mention errors randomly,

1).System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {656D8328-93F5-41A7-A48C-B42858161F25} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)). 

2)."RPC server is unavailable.(Exception from HRESULT:0x800706BA)" 

Can you please suggest how to resolve above mention issues ? "

Best Regards,